# Can't check out in sandbox mode with test account

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I have been trying it for an hour but I'm not sure what's wrong. I have created test accounts for both merchant and buyer via developer.paypal.com. Replaced woocommerce seller details with sandbox's. During checkout, it redirected me to sandbox page with the test merchant details which I think there's nothing wrong.

But, whenever I try to login with test buyer paypal account, it keeps saying "Please check your email address and password and try again", I'm pretty sure I enter the credentials correctly, I created another buyer account but it still saying the same thing. What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: 1)login to merchant account in a tab 2) In the same browser and another tab, During testing try login to buyer account.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with two sandbox accounts since Friday and really can't figure it out :( have contacted Paypal - will let you know if I crack it!